# Class initialization syntax in one line

Tags: c#, class

I have the following class

```
public class ListCode : List<int>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

which can be initialized this way:

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode() { 1, 2, 3};
myList.Code = "bar";
```

But it can also be initialized that way:

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode() { Code = "bar"};
myList.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Is there also a way to do this in one line? Like

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode() { 1, 2, 3, Code = "bar" }; //invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems not possible to do according to the reference in comments, but I can suggest to use constructor argument for this:

```
public class ListCode : List<int>
{
    public ListCode(string code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}

ListCode myList = new ListCode("bar") { 1, 2, 3};
```

That seems like the cleanest you can get :)

Comment: Small drawback: This will not work anymore if you want property initialization over multiple properties...

Comment: Yeah, I saw you answer, it's like inverted version :) But it of course depends on the likelihood of additional properties which one is better. You can by the way remove `int` to make it even shorter

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong but it is because this is 'syntactical sugar'. Both initialiser types address two different things..

### Index initialisation

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode() { 1, 2, 3};
```

is similar to

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode();
myList.Add(1); // myList[0] = 1;
myList.Add(2); // myList[1] = 2;
myList.Add(3); // myList[2] = 3;
```

### Property initialisation

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode() { Code = "bar"};
```

is the same as

```
ListCode myList = new ListCode();
myList.Code = "bar";
```

You cannot mix these as the compiler interprets them as one or the other.

However, this is possible...

```
public class ListCode : List<int>
{
    public ListCode(string code)
    {
        this.Code = code;
    }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}  

...

ListCode myList = new ListCode("bar") { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: `is the same as` should be `is similar to`. One significant difference is that in case of initializers the object is created 'on the side' and then subsequently assigned to the variable - there would be a difference if your initialization code threw an exception.

Comment: `ListCode myList = new ListCode() { 1, 2, 3};` can't be the same as `ListCode myList = new ListCode();myList[0] = 1;` because it throws a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement one of the additional constructors also implemented by List (passing IEnumerable)

```
public class ListCode : List<int>
{
    public ListCode(IEnumerable<int> content) : base(content) { }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to pass the content as parameter to the constructor and you are able to instantiate with additional property initialisation

```
var t = new ListCode(new [] { 1, 2, 3 }) { Code = "test" };
```